# Quartus isn't displaying Correctly

Tags: quartus

so , please look to the images attached , I downloaded Quartus with all its packages and reinstall it many times and still have that strange shape where the text is so small and also the gates are so small and also the wave drawn is so weird ,I tried to change the font from inside the program itself , it didn't work , also I changed the monitor resolution from 4K to 1080 , it didn't work also , anyone knows why why Quartus isn't displaying correctly.
any help ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this method :
go to your Quartus icon on desktop , click right on it , choose properties.
a window will appear , from the taps above , click on Compatibility.
from the buttons below ,click on 'Change high DPI settings'.
a window will appear , check mark on a box named 'override high DPI scaling behavior'
and from the drop down list below it , click it and choose either 'System' or 'System (enhanced)'.
this worked for me , I don't know of there are any other solutions or not.
I think this makes the system controls the display of the application and prevent the application from controlling its display by itself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: But I'm running a real OS not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Tools > Options > Font